# Share MacBook keyboard with CentOS Desktop

Tags: linux, macos, mac, keyboard, centos

I've looked online and there's a solution called `ShareMouse`, which is the Mac equivalent of Microsoft's `Mouse without borders`.  So far as I can tell there's isn't a Linux compatible way to do this.

Has anyone successfully been able to use their MacBook keyboard and trackpad to control a Linux Desktop? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it but [Synergy](http://synergy-project.org/) seems to do what you need.